# Git checkout master ; impossible

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a question, Ive cloned a repo from GitHub, and someone told me to switch the branch to master to apply new patch, like update kernel and after re switch to the repo branch.
But I don't know why I can't switch to `master`, do you know why?

I've tried some methods that I found here and there but still impossible.

EDIT: Adding pic, we see he used master branch except the 21.02 open wrt branch.

```
$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
$ git fetch
$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match
```

[image: branch]

[image: branches]

Comment: Try to checkout `main` branch

Comment: What does your `git branch` show?

Answer (score 4):

Try a `git branch -r` to see what branches are available.  Odds are they didn't use "master" as a branch name, and you need to adjust your `git checkout xxxx` command to match the branch name they used.

Comment: It is about open wrt, it is from master branch but I can't switch.

Comment: Why `-r` if he's just cloned the repo?

Comment: @Paolo because you want the remote branches.  Without the `-r` you will only get the local branches.

Comment: @EdwinBuck yeah, but they will be local too if he's just cloned

Comment: @Paolo Best to learn the right options and use them instead of assuming your stuff is correct (and possibly missing a new branch in the future).  If working with remote branches, work with remote branches instead of assuming your local branches contain all the remote one.  That way the muscle memory is there, and you don't script up something that fails later because it's not the kind of environment you use in you dev box.

Comment: @EdwinBuck fair enough

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make a contribution to the [`openwrt/openwrt`](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt) repository, branch master:

- [install GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation)
- [Create a Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) if you hadn't one already
- use [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) to authenticate yourself to GitHub

  ```
  echo myToken | gh auth login --with-token
  ```
- fork and clone the original repository (if you had not already created a fork), with [`gh repo fork`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_fork)

  ```
  gh repo fork openwrt/openwrt --clone --remote --renamote-name upstream
  ```
- create a local branch from the upstream repository

  ```
  git switch -c myFix upstream/master
  # work and add commits
  ```
- create a Pull Request from your current work from `myFix` branch, with [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create):

  ```
  gh pr create --title "The bug is fixed" --body "Everything works again" -b master
  ```